# Snowflake - Getting invalid identifier error while passing variables between SQL Stored Procs

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a Snowflake SQL stored procedure from where I'm trying to call the SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL function, but its erroring out as below:

```
`create or replace procedure testsproc()
RETURNS VARCHAR
language sql 
as
$$
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM non_existent_table;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHER THEN
    LET LINE := SQLCODE || ': ' || SQLERRM;
    INSERT INTO myexception VALUES (:LINE); -- this line works
    call SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL('MYEMAIL','abc@mail.com','Errors!!',LINE); -- this line is throwing the error invalid identifier 'LINE' (line 320)
    return line;
END;
$$`
```

I tried passing :LINE to system$send_email, it still isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's missing a colon, the same colon the script uses in the previous line:

Fixed:

```sql
    call SYSTEM$SEND_EMAIL('MYEMAIL','abc@mail.com','Errors!!', :LINE);
```

With that, I get the desired exception in my email:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, Felipe! That worked, I had the : there, was just missing a space after the comma. I really appreciate your help!!

Comment: I'm glad this worked - I also love how you are capturing and reporting exceptions here